# C# Chart with scrollbars

Tags: c#, winforms, charts

Anyone knows if this is possible? If yes is there any sample code so I can easily just put my data and get my chart?

Comment: @digEmAll do you know how to do it for any of them?

Comment: @user579674: no, I was just asking to know the answer to give...

Comment: @digEmAll so in any case you wouldn't no but you still asked. very helpful

Comment: Actually, I know winforms mschart, but someone already answered what I would have said myself, so I won't add my answer. I asked that, because you didn't specified the GUI subsystem and so I didn't know even if I was able to answer...

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as a `C# Chart`. I think what you are referring to is [Microsoft Chart Controls](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=130f7986-bf49-4fe5-9ca8-910ae6ea442c).

Check [here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/mschart/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=4418) for examples.

Comment: Yes that's right.. The point though is that I'm using C# and want a chart.. I've already checked the examples but they require more knowledge about the charts than just a simple copy/paste.. Has anyone used something similar and point me to the right direction?

Comment: @user579774 - Your question asks is there examples of how to put data into a chart and display....those examples do that. Scrollbars will come into play when your chart is zoomed.

Comment: I actually ask how to enable scrollbars.. I don't need it because I need zooming but because I have lot of data that won't fit in one screen.

Comment: You may want to view the question @beta has posted. Seems to cover what you are looking for.

Comment: the only problem is that I cannot find that isuserenabled property

Comment: @user579674: chart exposes ChartAreas collection (basically the layers in use, and normally only one is present). Every ChartArea has a `CursorX` and `CursorY` property related to the axis X and Y. Finally, they expose `IsUserEnabled/IsSelectionEnabled` properties so for example use something like `chart1.ChartAreas[0].CursorX.IsUserEnabled = true;`